# JQuery - populate two inputs with a percentage multiple of another input on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery novice here so please resist the urge to punish my ignorance. I am attempting to auto calculate and fill the value of two inputs on change of another. One should be 120% of the original. The other should be 140% of the original. Where am i going wrong here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function({   
    jQuery("#jform_listprice").on("change", function() {
        var val = +this.value || 0;
        var result_low = +val * 1.20.val();
        var result_high = +val * 1.40.val();
        jQuery("#jform_newprice").val(result_high.toFixed(2));
        jQuery("#jform_usedprice").val(result_low.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Comment: you can't call `.val()` on a non jQuery object `1.20.val()`

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#jform_listprice").on("change", function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(isNaN(val)) return; // Leave now if value is not a number
        var result_low = val * 1.20,
            result_high = val * 1.40;
        jQuery("#jform_newprice").val(result_high.toFixed(2));
        jQuery("#jform_usedprice").val(result_low.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Actually you don't need to typecast an integer or a float, JS tries to convert it as soon there's an arithmetic operation involved. If it fails to do so, the result will be NaN. Also .val() is a jQuery method, not a JS native one which you can call on a Number object.